# How can I get more ammo while in a Palace?

Tags: persona-5

After realizing how useful firearms are, I started using them a lot more. Unfortunately, they have **very** limited ammo. I have not been able to figure out how to get more without leaving the Palace and coming back another day. Is there a way to get more *without* leaving a Palace? If so, how?

Comment: I would post as an answer if I had a screenshot or more evidence to back it up, but when Morgana first explains ranged weapons, he explicitly states that the **only** way to replenish ammo is to leave the palace and return to the normal world.

Comment: @IvoCoumans oh, really? I must've missed that... too bad we can't take screenshots lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After realizing there were multiple pages of Infiltration Tools, I found that once you unlock Ace Tools, you have access to the recipe for Reserve Ammo, which works as a party ammo refill.

Alternatively, purchasing the Persona 4 Arena DLC bundle will give you 9 Evoker accessories. Equipping one to a party member will restore one bullet for them after each battle.

Other than this, the only way to get more ammo is to leave the Metaverse.